# Python3/Redis: redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command 'JSON.SET'

Tags: redis, python-3.6

I'm trying to run the sample program from [this RedisLabs page](https://redislabs.com/get-started-with-redis/).
I chose Option A - which was to set up the free Redis cloud server.
(Seems like if you install manually, then you have to add the JSON as a plugin.)
I'm able to connect and use other "set" commands, but getting error on JSON:

```
  File "C:\Users\nwalt\.virtualenvs\TDAmeritradeGetQuotes\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 901, in execute_command
    return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
  File "C:\Users\nwalt\.virtualenvs\TDAmeritradeGetQuotes\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 915, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "C:\Users\nwalt\.virtualenvs\TDAmeritradeGetQuotes\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 756, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command 'JSON.SET'
```

My Python test program (except put in the sample endpoint before posting):

```
    import redis
    import json
    import pprint
    
    host_info = "redis.us-east-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com"
    redisObj = redis.Redis(host=host_info, port=18274, password='xxx')
    
print ("Normal call to Redis")
redisObj.set('foo', 'bar')
value = redisObj.get('foo')
print(value)


capitals = {
     "Lebanon": "Beirut",
     "Norway": "Oslo",
     "France": "Paris"
 }
print ("capitals - before call to Redis")
pprint.pprint(capitals)


print("JSON call to Redis")
redisObj.execute_command('JSON.SET', 'doc', '.', json.dumps(capitals))
print("Data Saved, now fetch data back from redis")
reply = json.loads(redisObj.execute_command('JSON.GET', 'doc'))
print("reply from Redis get")
pprint.pprint(reply)
```

This is the screen shot from their website where I created the database.  I didn't see any option to enable JSON or add any modules.

[image]

Comment: It seems like the RedisJSON module is not loaded in your DB.

Comment: But it's RedisLabs clouds, and they said that was one of the choices to use in the link provided in my question.

Comment: Correct, but you have to pick the RedisJSON module from the modules list when you create the DB

Comment: Option A here - https://redislabs.com/get-started-with-redis/ doesn't list any steps about adding the module.  I put the screen shot into my question of how I created the DB.  My impression is that the cloud hosted version came with that module.

Comment: Please check this page https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/modules/modules-quickstart/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this was available when I created the REDIS database, but it is now.  When you create it on redislabs.com, you can turn on the modules, and pick one from the list.

[image]

Then use this library: "rejson" from    https://pypi.org/project/rejson/ to get the method "jsonset" method, using such code such as this:

```
rj = Client(host=config_dict['REDIS_CONFIG_HOST'], port=config_dict['REDIS_CONFIG_PORT'],                      password=config_dict['REDIS_CONFIG_PASSWORD'], decode_responses=True)

out_doc = {} 
out_doc['firstname'] = "John"
out_doc['lastname'] = "Doe"
rj.jsonset('config', Path.rootPath(), out_doc)
get_doc = rj.jsonget('config', Path.rootPath())
pprint.pprint(get_doc)
```

Comment: Note that as of redis-py 4.0.0 the `rejson` library is deprecated...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not used the cloud redis, in my local the Python don't load the JSON.SET
I just so make done, in this sample `https://onelinerhub.com/python-redis/save-json-to-redis`